# WSL Ubuntu 2020 LTS -Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried to install anaconda on Windows 10's Windows Subsystem for Linux Ubuntu 2020 LTS. The script had to be interrupted because my Anti Virus app has tried to sandbox the script. When I tried to re-run anaconda installer, it complained about the existing folder ~/anaconda3.

I tried to remove the folder but I've got Permission Denied errors. The folder and files belong to me. I set full file permissions to 777 and still get errors. I also logged into root, tried both `sudo su` and `sudo su -`, but even then I've got the same errors.

As the last step, I tried to remove the folder `anaconda3` using Windows 10 file explorer. I found the folder in there:

`\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimitted.Ubuntu...\LocalState\rootfs\home\<my account>`

and removed the problematic folder. When I log back to Ubuntu, it is still there and cannot be deleted; I get the same error.

I know I can reinstall WSL but I've done some pre-work to prepare the environment.

Thanks

EDIT. The folder disappeared after restarting a computer. I was wondering if I can refresh the subsystem without doing the restarts.

Comment: Try not to touch `AppData\Local\Packages` folder. Also try to whitelist that `rootfs` folder in that Anti-Virus program. What are the permission and owner of `/home` and `/home/username` folders?

Comment: I managed to install the Anaconda python. AntiVirus is now set to trust the script. Owner of `/home` is `root:root` and owner of a folder for my account is just me `myuser:myuser` and I was logged while trying to remove the anaconda3 folder. The permissions were set to full 777 (dwx swx dwx). I also tried to log as root. It did not help.